# grid widget remove base on model

Tags: sitefinity

I have this View that is using the grid-6+6 layout with two widget in each section. Base on the model I want to not display the one widget and move the number two widget into the first widget location. So if the Model has `IsAdmin = true` in layout 1 will display admin setting as well as number two widget in section two. If the model has `IsAdmin = false` two widget will display in layout 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can do customized logic in your widgets to show/hide based on the `IsAdmin` value.

The default Sitefinity layout template does not have that option.

Comment: I would need to hide it from the dom not the view. Also how would I move the layout in the grid 6x6

Comment: @Jefferson You can pass your model to Razor view to do the customized logic. For example, in your .cshtml file, you have `@if(model.IsAdmin){.....}`. By doing this, you can hide the widget form DOM completely. The grid 6x6 is easy enough to achieve in the presentation layer.

Comment: Not sure I understand how to do the grid in the presentation. If I drop the widget in section 1 and set it not to display it will still be in the section right ? The widget in section 2 will stat in that section and not move into section 2.